# Run Database At Android network

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, sqflite

I have 4 Android devices, i want to make One device as Database* Server, and Other Devices as Clients connecting to the database On server.

Note : any database possible.

thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a good idea to host a server on a mobile device. But if you want a phone to communicate with each other, try to connect on a mutual local host in the same network

Comment: thanks, but i need to do this necessary.

i have android devices only.